# how to search subfolders and files to get input form the user using java

Tags: java

how to search subfolders and files to get input form the user using java,

using listRoot method, but how to use with give a File class path

Comment: and what have you done ? i mean your part of code as you tried it.

Comment: try to add some code

Comment: Have a look at [Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html)

Answer (score 0):

use recursion on the top directory.Some thing as shown below

```
            class Main{

            public static void showFiles(File[] files) {
                for (File file : files) {
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        System.out.println("Folder is  " + file.getName());
                        showFiles(file.listFiles()); 
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("File is  " + file.getName());
                    }
                }

                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    File[] files = new File("your path").listFiles();
                    showFiles(files);
                }}
            }
```

Comment: Just beware, `File#listFiles` can return `null`, even when `File#exists` returns `true`.  Also, you're not checking to see if the `File` is a "file" or "directory", which would give you a `null` listing

Comment: its k but i want to search using user input

Comment: So, you don't null checks in "pseudocode"? It looks a lot like Java code to me ;)  And since SO is suppose to a professional based forum, it'd be nice to provide professional solutions (IMHO)

Comment: consider args in main method to get the user input and do something like 
File[] files = new File(args[0]).listFiles(); and also as suggested by MadProgrammer add a null check :-). cheers

Comment: to search file drive ex: to search from "E:\\" for get a subfolders